# Convert type Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1} to Array{Float64,1} in Julia

Tags: julia

I have an array of floats having some missing values, hence its type is `Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}`. Is there a command to convert the non-missing part into `Array{Float64,1}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three solutions, in order of preference (thanks to @BogumilKaminski for the first one):

```
f1(x) = collect(skipmissing(x))
f2(x) = Float64[ a for a in x if !ismissing(a) ]
f3(x) = x[.!ismissing.(x)]
```

`f1` lazy-loads the array with `skipmissing` (useful for e.g. iteration) and then builds the array via `collect`.

`f2` uses a `for` loop but is likely to be slower than `f1` since the final array length is not computed ahead of time.

`f3` uses broadcasting, and allocates temporaries in the process, and so is likely to be the slowest of the three.

We can verify the above with a simple benchmark:

```
using BenchmarkTools
x = Array{Union{Missing,Float64}}(undef, 100);
inds = unique(rand(1:100, 50));
x[inds] = randn(length(inds));
@btime f1($x);
@btime f2($x);
@btime f3($x);
```

Resulting in:

```
julia> @btime f1($x);
  377.186 ns (7 allocations: 1.22 KiB)

julia> @btime f2($x);
  471.204 ns (8 allocations: 1.23 KiB)

julia> @btime f3($x);
  732.726 ns (6 allocations: 4.80 KiB)
```

Comment: I would typically write `skipmissing(x)`, which returns a lazy wrapper, and `collect(skipmissing(x))` to materialize an array. This should be faster than `h`.

Comment: Yes that's much better. I'll add that solution and benchmarks when I'm next in front of a computer